# Как замерить время выполнения процедуры с высокой точностью?

Tags: oracle, plsql, таймер

Нужно замерить время выполнения процедуры. Время не достаточно высокое, поэтому миллисекунды критичны.

Как в этом коде вывести разницу с точностью до сотых секунды:

```sql
declare
  startdate date:= sysdate;
  enddate date;
begin
  -- Команды
  enddate := sysdate;
  dbms_output.put_line(???); -- вывести разницу с точностью до сотых секунды
end;
```

Comment: SYSDATE возвращает время с точностью до секунды. Используйте SYSTIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если точности до сотых секунды достаточно, то самое простое с ф-ей [GET_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#i1002765) так:

```sql
set timing on serveroutput on
declare
    t1 number := dbms_utility.get_time();
begin
    for r in (select * from all_objects) loop null; end loop; 
    dbms_output.put_line('query elapsed: '||(dbms_utility.get_time() - t1)/100); 
end;
/
```

> query elapsed: 3,09
>
> Elapsed: 00:00:03.121

---

Если всё таки точности не хватит, то надо воспользоваться [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C), который будет результатом вычитания двух отпечатков времени (*timestamp*).
Перевод в число секунд лучше сразу в функцию обернуть, как то так:

```sql
declare 
    function interval2Sec (interv interval day to second) return number is
    begin
        return 
            extract (hour   from (interv))*60*60+ 
            extract (minute from (interv))*60+ 
            extract (second from (interv));
    end;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('elapsed: '||interval2Sec (
        timestamp'2020-01-20 12:00:00.777' - timestamp'2020-01-20 11:58:00.333')||' sec.');
end;
/
```

> elapsed: 120,444 sec.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
  startdate date;
  enddate date;
begin
  startdate := systimestamp;
  -- Команды
  enddate := systimestamp;
  dbms_output.put_line('Elapsed time = ' || (enddate - startdate));
end;
/
```

Вот так оно выглядит на Oracle LiveSQL (кодом залепил первое, что пришло на ум - лишь бы не ноль в ответе):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Проверить пока не на чем_ - а почему, оператор интернет отключил? [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfa02b8fca938d9abd824d687f748952)

Comment: Только округляет упорно почему-то.
`dbms_output.put_line('Working time2: '||to_char(86400.0*(enddate-startdate),'fm99990D099999'));`
дает 1.0. Хотя в варианте 0xbd 
`dbms_output.put_line('Working time: '||(dbms_utility.get_time()-start_date)/100);`
дает 1.32

Comment: @0xdb Фиг знает почему, но мне он же упорно выводил только одну строку "1 rows affected"... а output отправлялся куда-то ещё, видимо.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов А чем Вам прямой вывод-то не угодил? умножения и прочие телодвижения - может, это от них чё не то?

Comment: @Akina
Прямой вывод не угодил тем, что по нему никак не узнать количество миллисекунд и секунд (в сутках не кратное десяти количество секунд). Надо домножать в любом случае. А без умножения то да, выводит длинную дробь. Хотя, конечно, тема должна быть рабочей с корректным домножением, это у меня лыжи не едут :)